# Get timestamps that are only on the hour mark

Tags: php

If I have, say, the following timestamps:

```
1382461201 - Tue, 22 Oct 2013 17:00:01 GMT
1382925601 - Mon, 28 Oct 2013 02:00:01 GMT
1383330601 - Fri, 01 Nov 2013 18:30:01 GMT
1383795001 - Thu, 07 Nov 2013 03:30:01 GMT
```

How would I create a loop that would go through each time stamp and **only print the ones that are on the hour mark** (17:00:01 and 02:00:01)?

Comment: It's funny that you can say what you want which demonstrates an understanding of what needs to be done but I don't see any actual effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @JohnConde Because I don't know where to start.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because no code is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result that you are looking for by using the built in [date function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

The date function takes two parameters, one is a formatting path and the second is a unix timestamp.

you can then iterate over the list of times and check to see if the minutes match the desired minutes and the seconds match the desired seconds. So if you just want any time within the first minute of the hour then you can do the following...

```
$time = 1382461201;
if(date('i', $time) == '00') {
    // Add this time value to your array of times within the first minute of every hour.
}
```

If you are after the first second as well then you can just add a second value of 's' to that formatting string that date requires.

Comment: Also, the hour mark will be 2:00:00 rather than 2:00:01